# Disable/enable fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and i am adding row by cloning it. I have a field as a drop-down menu and when the value of drop down is changed the corresponding disabled field is getting enabled.The problem i am getting is if i change the values of my drop-down of previous row the columns of current row also get enabled.Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```js
function disableField()
    {
    var Count = $('#dataTable tr').length;
    if (Count == 2){
        $("input").not('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
        $("input").prop('disabled', false);
    }
}

var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
    var cindex = 0;
    var quicklink = '' ;
    $(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(addrow) {
      var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
      
      if(count || !$('.id_100 option[value=code]').attr('selected','selected')){
        alert("Please fill the current row");
        return false;
      }
     
      
        var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
        var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
        cindex++;
     $clone.find(':input').not('select').not('.DeleteButton').val('').attr('disabled', true);
        $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
        //update ids of elements in row
        $clone.find("*").each(function() {
                var id = this.id || "";
                if(id != ""){
    
                var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                if (match.length == 2) {
       this.id = this.name + (cindex);
                }
                }
        });
       $tr.after($clone);
     
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="mainbox" class="mainbox"><tr><td>
     <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
     <div class="abcd"> <!--mainbox middlepanel start-->
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="maintable" class="maintable">
       <tr>
        <td valign="top">
         <div id="pageheadingpanel">
          <div id="pageheading">Quick Link Widget Configuration</div>
          <div id="pageheadingdate"><xsl:call-template name="formatted_date"/></div>
         </div>
        </td>  
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td height="100%" valign="top">
         <div class="y_scroll"  id="contentarea">
          <div class="contentarea"><!--contentarea  start-->
           <span id="box" class="box"> <!--rounded curve/border  start-->
           <div class="middlepanel"> <!--contentarea  box middlepanel start-->
     <div style="display:block"  id="textBox1" >
       <span id="box1" class="box"> 
        <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
        <div class="middlepanel"> 
        
    
    
    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" name="dataTable" class="graphtable">
      <thead>
    
        <tr>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
       <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>
    
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      
        <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="id0">
     
          <td>
       <div class="id_100">
        <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField()" >
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <xsl:for-each select="values from local db">
       <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description"/>
       <option value="{description}">
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
       </option>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </select>
         </div> </td>
          <td>
            <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext1" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
      
          </td>
          <td>
            <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext2" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
      
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext3" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
            
          </td>
       <td>
       <input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton"  type="button" />
       </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
      <div class="buttonarea">
      <ul>
        <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
    
      </ul>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Saurav, Question was not clear

Comment: Hello Krishna, when i add a second row and change the value of 'Select' field of first row the disabled fields of 2nd row gets enabled too.

Comment: Your logic is not clear. What you are trying to achieve? Share what logic you are trying to apply. Your disableField function is not taking any parameter. You should pass current dom by disableField(this) and receive it in function and do the job on current DOM's parent row.

Answer (score 0):

You have pass current target table tr element in onchange function

```js
 function disableField(targetElement)
    {
        
    var Count = $('#dataTable tr').length;
    if (Count == 2){
        $(targetElement).closest('tr').find('input').not('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);
    }else{
        $(targetElement).closest('tr').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
    }
}

var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
    var cindex = 0;
    var quicklink = '' ;
    $(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(addrow) {
      var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
      
      if(count || !$('.id_100 option[value=code]').attr('selected','selected')){
        alert("Please fill the current row");
        return false;
      }
     
      
        var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
        var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
        cindex++;
     $clone.find(':input').not('select').not('.DeleteButton').val('').attr('disabled', true);
        $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
        //update ids of elements in row
        $clone.find("*").each(function() {
                var id = this.id || "";
                if(id != ""){
    
                var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                if (match.length == 2) {
       this.id = this.name + (cindex);
                }
                }
        });
       $tr.after($clone);
     
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="mainbox" class="mainbox"><tr><td>
     <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
     <div class="abcd"> <!--mainbox middlepanel start-->
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="maintable" class="maintable">
       <tr>
        <td valign="top">
         <div id="pageheadingpanel">
          <div id="pageheading">Quick Link Widget Configuration</div>
          <div id="pageheadingdate"><xsl:call-template name="formatted_date"/></div>
         </div>
        </td>  
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td height="100%" valign="top">
         <div class="y_scroll"  id="contentarea">
          <div class="contentarea"><!--contentarea  start-->
           <span id="box" class="box"> <!--rounded curve/border  start-->
           <div class="middlepanel"> <!--contentarea  box middlepanel start-->
     <div style="display:block"  id="textBox1" >
       <span id="box1" class="box"> 
        <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
        <div class="middlepanel"> 
        
    
    
    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" name="dataTable" class="graphtable">
      <thead>
    
        <tr>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
       <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>
    
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      
        <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="id0">
     
          <td>
       <div class="id_100">
        <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField(this)" >
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <xsl:for-each select="values from local db">
       <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description"/>
       <option value="{description}">
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
       </option>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </select>
         </div> </td>
          <td>
            <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext1" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
      
          </td>
          <td>
            <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext2" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
      
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext3" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
            
          </td>
       <td>
       <input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton"  type="button" />
       </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
      <div class="buttonarea">
      <ul>
        <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
    
      </ul>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Krishna .Thanks for your answer but i have already tried this. It contains two problems. 1)The delete button of first row will never get enabled.2)When i add third row the delete button is already enabled

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `this` (current) element to  onChange function.

```
<select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField(this)" >
```

Now you have to use `this`  to enable , disable your element inside `tr`.

```
 function disableField(ele) {
  var Count = $('#dataTable tr').length;
  if (Count == 2) {
    $(ele).closest('tr').find("input").not('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $(ele).closest('tr').find("input").prop('disabled', false);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have already tried this. It contains two problems. 1)The delete button of first row will never get enabled.2)When i add third row the delete button is already enabled.

Comment: Nop. Always catch your element from `this` and it's work. Recheck your code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing couple of things wrong here see the difference with you code.
you shouldn't call `.not('.DeleteButton')` when adding a new row and `Count == 2` causing problem see i have fixed it.

```js
function disableField(e)
{
 $(e).closest('tr').find("input").prop('disabled', false);
}

var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
    var cindex = 0;
    var quicklink = '' ;
    $(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(addrow) {
      var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
      
      if(count || !$('.id_100 option[value=code]').attr('selected','selected')){
        alert("Please fill the current row");
        return false;
      }
     
        var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
        var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
        cindex++;
     $clone.find('input:text').val('').attr('disabled', true);
  $clone.find('input:button').attr('disabled', true);
        $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
        //update ids of elements in row
        $clone.find("*").each(function() {
                var id = this.id || "";
                if(id != ""){
    
                var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                if (match.length == 2) {
       this.id = this.name + (cindex);
                }
                }
        });
       $tr.after($clone);
     
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="mainbox" class="mainbox"><tr><td>
     <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
     <div class="abcd"> <!--mainbox middlepanel start-->
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="maintable" class="maintable">
       <tr>
        <td valign="top">
         <div id="pageheadingpanel">
          <div id="pageheading">Quick Link Widget Configuration</div>
          <div id="pageheadingdate"><xsl:call-template name="formatted_date"/></div>
         </div>
        </td>  
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td height="100%" valign="top">
         <div class="y_scroll"  id="contentarea">
          <div class="contentarea"><!--contentarea  start-->
           <span id="box" class="box"> <!--rounded curve/border  start-->
           <div class="middlepanel"> <!--contentarea  box middlepanel start-->
     <div style="display:block"  id="textBox1" >
       <span id="box1" class="box"> 
        <div class="toppanel"><ul><li></li></ul></div>
        <div class="middlepanel"> 
        
    
    
    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" name="dataTable" class="graphtable">
      <thead>
    
        <tr>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
       <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>
    
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      
        <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="id0">
     
          <td>
       <div class="id_100">
        <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField(this)" >
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <xsl:for-each select="values from local db">
       <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="description"/>
       <option value="{description}">
        <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
       </option>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </select>
         </div> </td>
          <td>
            <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500" disabled="true" class="objinputtext1" size="85" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
      
          </td>
          <td>
            <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50" disabled="true" class="objinputtext2" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
      
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="15" disabled="true" class="objinputtext3" size="35" value="{//RESPONSE}"  />
            
          </td>
       <td>
       <input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton"  type="button" />
       </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
      <div class="buttonarea">
      <ul>
        <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
    
      </ul>
     
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As semple as possible.

```js
function add_row(){
 var code = Math.floor((Math.random() * 99999999999999) + 1)
 var row =  '<tr id="row-'+code+'"'+  '>'+
     '<td>'+
      '<select '+ 'onchange="disabledatr(' +"'"+code+"'" + ')"' + '>'+
        '<option value="true">disabled</option>'+
        '<option value="false">not disabled</option>'+
      '</select>'+
     '</td>'+
     '<td><input type="text" disabled="false"></td>'+
    '</tr>'


   $("table").append(row )
 }

  function disabledatr(code){
 
   var isdisabled=event.target.value

   $("table #row-"+code+ " input").prop('disabled', (isdisabled=='true')?true:false)
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>

</table>


<button id="add" onclick="add_row()">add</button>
```